# HTTP/1.1 Headers

Tags: http, ip

Gracias a la versión HTTP/1.1, se introdujo una cabecera que permite a
diferentes sitios Web compartir la misma dirección IP, podrían ayudarme en descubrir cual es el nombre de esa cabecera? Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Cabecera: `host`

Es parte del protocolo HTTP 1.1.

Específicamente, el protocolo HTTP 1.1 incluye un encabezado llamado `host:` que especifica a que sitio web en un servidor en particular está intentando acceder el cliente.

Entonces, si `perritos.net` y `perfiles.org` comparten `192.0.32.10` y su navegador está tratando de obtener contenido de `http://perritos.net/comida`, la solicitud HTTP específica se vería así:

```
GET /comida HTTP / 1.1
host: perritos.net
```

Si la URL deseada es `http://perfiles.org/todos`, la solicitud se vería así

```
GET /todos HTTP / 1.1
host: perfiles.org
```

En ambos casos, habría un socket TCP entre tu computadora y el puerto 80 del servidor. El servidor sabría obtener contenido de, por ejemplo,  `/var/www/perritos.net` o `/var/www/perfiles.org/` basado en el encabezado `host`.

Habría otros encabezados para las *cookies* y otras cosas como el tipo de navegador y el contenido permitido, pero el encabezado `host` es específicamente lo que permite al servidor web saber qué sitio web virtual se desea.

Hay más en el **[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)**.

Esta es también la razón por la cual los sitios HTTPS deben tener su propia dirección IP: el intercambio de claves *SSL* y la verificación del certificado tienen lugar antes de la transacción HTTP, por lo que el servidor HTTP no sabrá entregar el certificado de `perfiles.org` o `perritos.net` cuando recibe una conexión HTTPS en el puerto 443 de 192.0.32.10.

Comment: Para el caso que comentas al final, existen los certificados multi-dominio, por lo que generalmente si es posible tener varios dominios alojados en un servidor compartiendo la misma IP y servir contenido via HTTPS.

Comment: interesante, hasta ahi no he llegado, seguire fundamentando en ello, gracias paisano.

Comment: ¡Un saludo paisano! No se ve mucha gente de nuestro pueblo por aquí, es un gusto. :)